# Why Does Android Studio Unfold My Code?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

When I'm writing code in Android Studio, it has a habit of unfolding code that I've already folded. It seems to happen any time a `{` is inserted into my code and it has to reparse things. If a single `{` is inserted, it will unfold code above the place I'm working at, and if the first `{` is unmatched and I insert another `{` it'll unfold code below. It does not refold the code once it finished parsing. Is there something I can use to fix this or do I just need to keep shaking my fist at my monitor?

Comment: Check out your IDE preferences for automatic formatting.

Comment: I see a close vote, but last time I checked IDE questions are on-topic.

Comment: If it were an autoformatting issue it would stop unfolding code that it's autoformatted before. It doesn't seem predictable which methods it will decide to unfold.